# Creating time stamps and repeat in the same column

Tags: r, date, vector, rep

I want to create a vector of time stamps consisting of 60 monthly dates and repeat the process for `n` number of times. That means, if `n = 2`, the vector should contain 120 times stamps.

A single vector of time stamps I am creating in this way,

```
t <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "month")
```

To repeat it `n` number of times I am doing the following,

```
n <- 2
X <- data.frame(replicate(n, seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "month")))
Y <- stack(X)[,"values", drop=FALSE]
head(Y)

> head(Y)
  values
1  16071
2  16102
3  16130
4  16161
5  16191
6  16222
```

As you see the values are not in time format anymore. My question is how to retain the time format in the vector Y? Is there any smarter way to do this problem?

Comment: See `help("rep")`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't think about `rep`. Apparently, this works, `qq <- rep(seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "month"), 2)
`

Comment: BTW `seq` has a `length.out` argument that you might find helpful: `seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), length.out = 60, by = "month")`. And try to find another name for your vector, `t` is taken.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the 'zoo' package, there is an old thread here https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2010-March/233159.html

where they talk about sort of the same problem.

Either way, after installing zoo you can do

```
as.Date(16071)
```

and it will return the date in date format. Hope this makes sense.